# Using node-schedule from another component/js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I'm trying to understand javascript and cron.
I need to 'update' variable every n second(s). 
Here's the example:

```
/*===cron.js===*/
    var schedule = require('node-schedule')

    var hello = initHello()

    function initHello () {
        return 'hello'
    }

    function changeHelloToWorld () {
        return 'world'
    }

    function cron () {
        //change value to 'world' after n second(s)
        schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * * *', function () {
            hello = changeHelloToWorld()
            return hello
        })
        return hello
    }


    module.exports = {
        cron
    }

/*===index.js===*/
var Hello = require('./cron')
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

//if I use this, it works. It prints 'world' instead of 'hello' after n seconds
schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * * *', function () {
    console.log(Hello.cron())
})

//But if I use this, it doesn't work.
//It prints 'hello' only once
console.log(Hello.cron())
```

From the example above, my question is, how can I get new value from cron.js without using scheduleJob() in index.js?
How can I make sure that the result is 'world' instead of 'hello' without using scheduleJob() in index.js?

Comment: you have killed internet with the while loop

Comment: delete the while loop and just type console.log(Hello.cron())

Comment: Hmm.. I'm using `while` for simulating that the app is always running. Is that the bad idea?

How can I make sure that the result is 'world' instead of 'hello' without using `scheduleJob()` in index.js?

Comment: I dont understand the console.log outside the scheduleJob in index will always print 'hello' only. the cron code will return world only after 10 seconds. So you should call Hello.cron() after 10 seconds to get the world value